# Drop Down hiding values

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I want the the day value of 1 to show only if the user selects a month and not the blank value, but it is not working...I think the function is wrong.  I want the 1 in the day drop down to have display none only if month has not been seleted.  Please help me....

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(x) {
var mon = document.getElementById(x).innerHTML
if (mon == "") {
document.getElementById("one").style.display="none";
} else {
document.getElementById("one").style.display="";
}
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
Calendar<br>
<hr align="left" width="200px"/>


--Year ------ Month ----- Day<br>
<select name="year">
<option value="defaulty"></option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>

<select name="month" onchange="show(this)">
<option id="defaultm"></option>
<option id="January">January</option>
<option id="February">February</option>
<option id="March">March</option>
<option id="April">April</option>
<option id="May">May</option>
<option id="June">June</option>
<option id="July">July</option>
<option id="August">August</option>
<option id="September">September</option>
<option id="October">October</option>
<option id="November">November</option>
<option id="December">December</option>
</select>

<select name="day">
<option id="defaultd" value="defaultd"></option>
<option id="one" value="one" style="display:none">1</option>

</select>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want for the day column to only be available if the month has been selected correct? If I am understanding you correctly this will do the trick.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function show() {

            if (document.getElementById("month").selectedIndex != 0) {
                document.getElementById("day").disabled = false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("day").disabled = true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    Calendar<br>
    <hr align="left" width="200px"/>
    <form actn="">
        --Year ------ Month ----- Day<br>
        <select name="year" id="year">
            <option value="defaulty"></option>
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
        </select>
        <select name="month" id="month" onchange="show()">
            <option value="defaultm"></option>
            <option value="January">January</option>
            <option value="February">February</option>
            <option value="March">March</option>
            <option value="April">April</option>
            <option value="May">May</option>
            <option value="June">June</option>
            <option value="July">July</option>
            <option value="August">August</option>
            <option value="September">September</option>
            <option value="October">October</option>
            <option value="November">November</option>
            <option value="December">December</option>
        </select>
        <select name="day" id="day" disabled="disabled">
            <option id="defaultd" value="defaultd"></option>
            <option id="one" value="one">1</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
```